# View special chars in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am using both [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) and [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/) and I prefer ST3 over Notepad2 as it has a lot of great features. One thing I miss very much though is the possibility to view special characters in a logfile.

If I have a logfile with this one line in it (`<null>` is the HEX char `0x00`):

```
ERROR: Received invalid data string [<null><null>e<null><null>test</null>]
```

If I open it in Notepad2 I get this view:

[image]

If I open it in ST3 I get this HEX view:

[image]

Is it possible to get the same view in ST3 as in Notepad2, so I can see the special characters?

Comment: To remove `NUL` chars - with regex enabled, find and replace `\x00`..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found this option which can be set in the User Settings:

```
// Files containing null bytes are opened as hexadecimal by default
"enable_hexadecimal_encoding": false
```

This gives exactly what I wanted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this:

https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/HexViewer

But that does not map `\0` to `NUL`, this may cause alignment issue (unless you have a fixed-width `NUL` glyph in your font).

Comment: This is still a HEX view which I do not want - maybe I can use the plugin for other stuff but it doesn't solve my question